# What is causing web browsing delays?

Tags: networking, internet

When browsing the Internet, every time a page is opened or a link is followed, the browser always waits for a few seconds on "Sending request... " "Looking up... " or sometimes "Waiting for... ".

This happens when using Firefox or Chrome, on both wired and wifi, Windows 7, Ubuntu 11.04 and Fedora 15.

Changing DNS servers on the router from the ISP's to whatever Namebench recommended.

It's not just a slow connection, because sustained download speed on BitTorrent, SpeedTest etc is pretty fast.

[image]

Comment: So if you ruled out individual machines and DNS, then it will probably be the router itself. Are you using a cable modem too and which models do you own?

Comment: @slhck it's an ADSL modem built into the router - My ISP (Orange) sent me the router (Netgear DGN1000) but I had it with my old ISP (O2) at the same address, with a different router.

Comment: "Looking up" is the DNS delay. Be careful with Google/OpenDNS. I find its best to keep the ISP provided DNS as the primary DNS, with Google/OpenDNS as the secondary. Your ISPs DNS normally has a much lower latency, and also helps you get to content cached by your ISP for increased browsing speed.

Comment: well you could use wireshark see if anything stands out re DNS

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the ping time on [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net)? The most likely problem is latency in your case, which has a major impact on performance.

Another metric to watch for is upload speed. I have a fast internet connection (50 Mb/s) but the bad part is the upload speed is pathetic (2 Mb/s), making overall browsing slower than I'd like.

Comment: +1 for mentioning different types of tests (and congratulations on reaching 10,000 points).

Comment: Thanks, but my ping time is respectable. Take a look at the Speedtest link to see my results. My upload speed is 1Mbps which is enough to send the small amounts of data required to request a webpage.

Comment: @Blazemore: what exactly does respectable mean?

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: thank you! It took me a while to get to 10k :)

Comment: @alex it means it was 36ms on that test, and I never get lag in online games. It seems to only be DNS lookups that have the issue.

Comment: @Blazemore: incredibly strange... I agree, your ping time is respectable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving yourself a static IP address?

It sounds like it's a DNS lookup problem so maybe have a search around for that.  I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avahi/+bug/94940) bug report and it's worked for a couple of other people with the same problem as you so give it a go.

If that doesn't work, try borrowing a spare router from someone else to test if it really is a router problem.

Comment: Do you mean a static IP from Orange, or give my computer a static IP (bypassing DHCP)?
If you mean the latter, I don't think that's an issue since it occurs to all devices connected to the router.
If you mean the former, Orange charge a fortune (probably) for static IPs.

Do you have a spare router? Don't forget it's ADSL so you can't just drop one in. It would have to be reconfigured for my ISP, or if it was a cable modem, I'd have to reconfigure my current router to act as a straight ADSL modem. I have a Linksys cable router in a cupboard but I don't know how to use my Netgear as a modem.

Comment: I mean just give your computer a static IP.  I can do it on Windows, not so sure on Linux but I expect you know how to.  You're right, it may not work, but it's worth a try.  As far as routers are concerned, I don't have an Orange one, but someone else at Uni might do.  You could just try plugging your Linksys one in and give it a go.  I've done that with BT as my ISP and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is IPv6. Maybe your PC tries AAAA (IPv6 address record) queries first, and falls back to IPv4 after a timeout. What OS do you use?

Comment: As I said, it happens on Windows 7, Ubuntu 11.04 and Fedora 15.
Both wired and wireless (different adaptors) so it's not some kind of driver or even firmware issue.

Comment: If AAAA queries are timing out, then the DNS server is *broken*. My system tries IPv6 first, too, but the DNS queries properly result in an empty reply, in milliseconds.

Comment: My OS at the moment (Ubuntu) is set to ignore ipv6